# How to use GPU with qiskit as default and then use parallel GPU setup in distributed computing?

Tags: qiskit, programming, simulation

I have a GTX 1600 GPU on my computer and I am confused on how to use cuQuantum, Tensorflow or torch etc to enable GPU for qiskit. Further, one of my friends also have a GPU, we want to use both GPUs but on each of our computers to implement qiskit code in parallel.

Some of the work I have done till now is,

1. I have downloaded docker and cuQuantum. Also, pip installed Tensorflow, torch and nimba but all these have some dependencies issues. Where I'm stuck.
2. I think a software called DASK can help perform parallel computing but i don't know how to use it,

What I am looking for is,

1. A step by step guide to use docker with cuQuantum or cuda to run qiskit.
2. Also, if I need to install Tensorflow or qiskit-aer-gpu etc then how to know what dependencies to solve for.